# Displaying a button to open a pop up window in HTML/JS and CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to display 2 buttons side by side when you click on the button "Land" present below the "Water" button. Both those buttons should be able to open up pop windows for which the code i have already included. I have tried to implement the button code but when i click on "Land" button everything disappears. How can i fix this?

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/fku50o9v/2/

Here is my current code:

```js
function popup(id){
if($("#"+id).hasClass( "vis" )){
   $("#"+id).removeClass( "vis" );
}else{
  $(".dropdown-content").removeClass( "vis" );
  $("#"+id).addClass( "vis" );
  }
}
```

```css
#outer
{
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.inner
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

    
.msgBtn2{
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    height: 2.5rem;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: blue;
    background-color: #ffff;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0.3rem  rgba(121,121,121,0.70);
    
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown-content {
  min-width: 160px;
  top: 50px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  color: red;
}
.dropdown-content button{
  color: red;
  margin: 5px;
  display: block;
}

.vis {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outer">
        <div class="inner">
        <div class="dropdown">
  <span><button class="msgBtn2" onclick="popup('water');" >Water</button></span>
  <div id="water" class="dropdown-content">
  <!--<button type="submit" class="msgBtn2">land</button>!-->
    <span><button class="msgBtn2" onclick="popup('land');" >land</button></span>
    <div id="land" class="dropdown-content">
     <button  target="popup" 
  onclick="window.open('http://google.com/popup','popup','width=600,height=600'); return false;" class="msgBtn2">Workflow</button> 
    </div>
  <button type="submit" class="msgBtn2">river</button> 
  <button type="submit" class="msgBtn2">ocean</button> 
  </div>
  
</div></div>
        
     
    </div>
```

Comment: $(".dropdown-content").removeClass( "vis" ); -  hides the buttons when they are clicked

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work.  Like Svela mentioned you're "hiding" all elements but the one you're clicking. You need to keep the parent visible. This is just a dirty implementation, I'm pretty sure there are more elegant ways, but it should give you a good idea :D ... I think..

```js
function popup(id){
let element = $("#"+id);
if(element.hasClass( "vis" )){
   element.removeClass( "vis" );
}else{
  $(".dropdown-content").removeClass( "vis" );
  element.addClass( "vis" );
  element.parent(".dropdown-content").addClass( "vis" );
  }
}
```